# p4 change not working with gvim

Tags: vim, perforce, perforce-client-spec

I use perforce as source code repository. `p4 change` command is used to create a changelist of opened files. If I set `setenv EDITOR gvim` and then run this command then gvim opens and I add some description and then save and quit. I get below error. Same error does not come if EDITOR is not set, I mean in that case vim opens. Any idea to fix this issue?

```
sachina@inn-sachina-vm[285] p4 change
Error in change specification.
Error detected at line 29.
Change description missing.  You must enter one.
Hit return to continue...
```

Comment: You could give a LOT more details, for example what operating system you're on, etc. But, just speculating, I'm guessing that you need to set your editor to 'gvim -f', where `-f` is the "foreground" option: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html

Comment: Thanks, doing setenv EDITOR 'gvim -f' solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications that invoke `EDITOR` assume that the command **blocks until editing is done** and the editor was closed. While true for `vim`, the GUI version `gvim` launches in the background; i.e. the command returns immediately.

You can avoid this via the `:help -f` command-line option:

```
setenv EDITOR 'gvim -f'
```